# Prove a constant is even

Tags: coq

Given the inductive definition of evenness, how is it best proved that, say, 1024 is an even number?
Repeating `apply even_S` down to zero is certainly not the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating `apply even_S` is not the way. `repeat apply even_S` is. If `even_S` is a constructor, there's also `repeat constructor`.

```
Inductive even : nat -> Prop :=
| even_O : even O
| even_S : forall n, even n -> even (S (S n)).

Goal (even 1024). repeat apply even_S. exact even_O. Qed.
Goal (even 1024). repeat constructor. Qed. (* also finds even_O, would leave as goal otherwise *)
```

Answer (score 4):

As HTNW pointed out, you can use Ltac automation to produce such a proof. This has the disadvantage of producing a large proof term `even_S (even_S ... even_O)`, thus slowing down proofs. In this case, it is better to reformulate the goal using a boolean decision procedure:

```
Fixpoint evenb (n : nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | 0 => true
  | 1 => false
  | S (S m) => evenb m
  end.

Lemma evenb_correct : forall n, evenb n = true <-> even n.
(* Fun exercise! *)
```

Coq can prove that `evenb 1024 = true` simply by evaluating the left-hand side:

```
Goal (even 1024). apply evenb_correct. reflexivity. Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks indeed, Arthur. Why sometimes it's more practical not to use a type but a function is new knowledge to me.